# Error while running annonate function for grouped bar chart: annotate() got multiple values for argument 'xy'

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, annotate

I am using a dictionary "my_dictionary" containing key and a list containing two int items. 
Dictionary - `{key : [men_mean, women_mean]}`.
Counts:
Values of men_mean and women_mean are close to 2000.
Total keys are 400.

I am getting following error:

Error:

```
----> 5         ax.annotate('{}',format(height), xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height), xytext=(0,maximum), 
textcoords="offset points", ha='center', va='bottom')

TypeError: annotate() got multiple values for argument 'xy'
```

Code:

```py
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


labels, list_item = zip(*sorted(my_dictionary.items())
for key, item in my_dictionary.items():
    men_means.append(item[0])
    women_means.append(item[1])


x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, men_means, width, label='Men')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, women_means, width, label='Women')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()


def autolabel(rects, maximum):
    """Attach a text label above each bar in *rects*, displaying its height."""
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, maximum),  # 3 points vertical offset
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')


autolabel(rects1, max(men_means))
autolabel(rects2, max(women_means))

fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Comment: The code you have given doesn't yield the error you have given, as it in fact fails much earlier to first a syntax error due to an unmatched parenthesis, then a name error due to an undeclared name `my_dictionary`

Comment: Yes. This is not full code. Dictionary code is separate and big, so I didn't posted entire code. Sorry. But I did mentioned example dictionary for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the comma `,` between `{}` and `format()`, it should be dot `.`:

```
ax.annotate('{}'.format(height), ...)
```

with a comma, the function `annotate` considers that `{}` is the first argument and `format(height)` is the second argument. since the second argument of the function is `xy`, it thinks you've passed two values to `xy`, one by position, and then one by keyword `xy=`.

Instead, what you wanted to do is to pass a formatted string `'{}'.format()` to the first argument (`s`) of the function